# leaflet maps add raster

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, maps

i want to add a raster file in the leaflet map,after from searching i find this [example](https://github.com/GeoTIFF/georaster-layer-for-leaflet-example) where is that i need i think georaster-layer-for-leaflet-example.

the code look simple js :

```
var parse_georaster = require("georaster");

var GeoRasterLayer = require("georaster-layer-for-leaflet");

// initalize leaflet map
var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 5);

// add OpenStreetMap basemap
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var url_to_geotiff_file = "example_4326.tif";

fetch(url_to_geotiff_file)
  .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
  .then(arrayBuffer => {
    parse_georaster(arrayBuffer).then(georaster => {
      console.log("georaster:", georaster);

      /*
          GeoRasterLayer is an extension of GridLayer,
          which means can use GridLayer options like opacity.
          Just make sure to include the georaster option!
          http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#gridlayer
      */
      var layer = new GeoRasterLayer({
          georaster: georaster,
          opacity: 0.7
      });
      layer.addTo(map);

      map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());

  });
});
```

error :

```
GeoTIFF: Object
bundle.js:16 Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/Users/username/Downloads/georaster-layer-for-leaflet-example-master/example_4326.tif. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
1.georaster @ bundle.js:16
bundle.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at Object.1.georaster (bundle.js:16)
    at s (bundle.js:1)
    at e (bundle.js:1)
    at bundle.js:1
```

any idea how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that the tiff should be hosted online: "URL scheme must be "http" or "https".
Try putting your tiff online somewhere such as on github or the server you plan to host your map, the on the line `var url_to_geotiff_file = "example_4326.tif";`, use the full URL for the tiff.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue!

Steps to solve the issue:

1) You can solve it by, publishing it on a local web server such as apache tomcat (by default your file URL will be something like: http://localhost:8080/file_name.tif).

2) Now if you will try to load the map georaster layer, you will get an error such as this:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/file_name.tif' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

3) To solve the above problem add the extension `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin` to your chrome browser and enable it.

It will work then!